# I can't let the scrollview scroll when having a view on top of it

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

In SwiftUI, how would you let the scrollview scrollable by putting a view on top of it?

So basically, I have a `ZStack` that contains a `ScrollView` a `View`.
Both are expending to take the entire available space within the `ZStack`.

In this scenario, the `View` is on top of the `ZStack`. `View` also contains let's say a `Button` and an added `TapGesture` on some areas.

How would I allow the `ScrollView` to be still scrollable through the `View`?

Thanks for any help on that!!

Some code to illustrate, although incomplete.

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        ScrollView {
            SomeCell() // Looped
        }
        HUD() // The view talked above
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you played around with the `allowsHitTesting(_ enabled: Bool)` modifier?

Comment: I did, it blocks completely the HUD. which means, can't press any button or anything.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known SwiftUI bug according [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62061093/swiftui-overlay-blocking-list-scroll-events). I've also run into the same issue and I don't believe there is a native SwiftUI solution. You may have to fall back on a UIViewRepresentable.

For my use case, I just wanted the horizontal edges of my scroll view to have a "faded" appearance which I was able to accomplish with using a mask instead of an overlay, but I'm not sure if that helps in your case.

```swift
ScrollView {
   Text("Hello")
}.mask(
    LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [
                                Colors.background.opacity(0),
                                Colors.background.opacity(1),
                                Colors.background.opacity(0)
                            ]),
                            startPoint: .leading,
                            endPoint: .trailing
                        )
                    )
```